# RegEx for Google Analytics that picks text within urls

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to build a RegEx that picks urls that end with "/topic". These urls have a different number of folders so whereas one might be www.example.com/pijamas/topic another could be www.example.com/pijamas/strippedpijamas/topic

What regular expression can I use to do that? My attempt is ^www.example.com/[a-zA-Z][1,]/topic$ but this hasn't worked. Even if it worked I'd like to have a shorter RegEx to do this really.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you, A.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^www\.example\.com\/[\w\/]*topic$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a few changes to your regex. Firstly, the dot (`.`) is a special character and needs to be escaped by prefacing it with a backslash.

Secondly, you probably meant `{1,}` instead of `[1,]` – the latter defines a character class. You can substitute `{1,}` with `+`.

Then there's the fact that your second URL has one more subdirectory, so you need to somehow incorporate a `/` into your regex.

Putting all this together:

```
^www\.example\.com/[a-zA-Z]+(/[a-zA-Z]+)*/topic$
```

To shorten it, you can use the `i` option to match regardless of case, cutting down the two `[a-zA-Z]` to `[a-z]`. Try this online [here](https://regex101.com/r/b9uBlv/1).

Comment: The example urls would work, but a number is perfectly valid in a url, which [a-zA-Z] would exclude.

Comment: @TrevDavies True - other characters might have to be added too if the goal is to match an arbitrary URL. However, I worked from the regex the OP provided and if that is all he needs …

Comment: I have changed example.com for my url and it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @alex_cargo Without knowing exactly what you did, it is not possible to help you. Please post your exact regex and URLs.

Comment: I changed example for my root domain name and .com for .co.uk, that's all

Comment: @alex_cargo like I said, you will need to post the exact information. From your comment, it is not possible to see what is wrong.